# Can an inner class of a template class be a non-template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I am making a template class with an inner utility class.  All specializations of the template want the same inner class:

```
template<...> class Outer {
    class Inner { };
};
```

That gives me `Outer<...>::Inner` but I want all `Inner` to be the same type, as if I'd just written:

```
class Inner { };
template <...> class Outer { };
```

or if `Outer` were simply not a template class:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner { };
};
```

giving me `Outer::Inner`.  I'd like to have `Outer::Inner` work for all `Outer<>` if that's possible (just for namespace/clarity reasons).  Otherwise of course I can just move `Inner` out.

Comment: I'm quite certain the answer is no, but I'm hoping somebody proves me wrong because I happen to be in a similar situation :)

Comment: I'm only *fairly* certain the answer is no but I'm hoping for clever workarounds too...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The nested class can be a non-template, but every instantiation of the template will have its own nested class because they're (otherwise) unrelated types. You can do

```
namespace detail {

class Inner {};

} // detail

template<...>
class Outer {
    typedef detail::Inner Inner;
};
```

Comment: I'm forgetting my namespace details - can `class Inner` be hidden, now, like it is in a "true" inner class?  Or will any including code be able to have at it?

Comment: @Nate The above behaves as with any `typedef`. `Inner` can be left incomplete with only a declaration that is not also a definition (i.e. `class Inner;`), with all the caveats that it implies. But it must be declared (the name `detail::Inner` must refer to something), or else it can't be `typedef`'d.

Answer (score 14):

The way I've done this in the past is using inheritance:

```
class DummyBase{
protected:
    class Inner{
        //etc...
    };
};

template<...> class Outer : public DummyBase{
    //etc...
};
```

Comment: +1, because this makes `Outer<>::Inner` a real class name. So `class Outer<>::Inner x;` or `friend class Outer<>::Inner;` would still work, whereas the `typedef` solution will fail there.

Answer (score -1):

It will be unique for each instantiation of Outer. I.e.,

```
Outer<int>::Inner will be a different type from Outer<double>::Inner
```

Comment: That fact is well-known to the OP as he has clearly stated it in his problem